# multiple addition of header file even after checking

Tags: regex, perl

I want to add  in a .C file incase its not present. Using Perl

MY CODE SNIPPET

```
my $flag = 0;
my $pos = 0;
open(FILE, $input) or die $!;
my @lines = <FILE>;

foreach(@lines) 
{
   $pos++;

   #checks for #include where it can add stdint.h
   if ($_ =~ (m/#include/))
   {                

       #prevents multiple addition for each header file 
       if($flag == 0)
       {                     
             #checks whether stdint already present or not
             unless($_ =~ m/#include <stdint.h>/ )
             {         
             splice @lines,$pos,0,"#include <stdint.h>"."\n";
             $flag = 1;
        }
    }
   }
}
```

But my code is adding stdint.h everytime it runs which means multiple addition for every run.

whats wrong with the code

```
unless($_ =~ m/#include <stdint.h>/){
```

doesn't work even if i use

```
unless($_ =~ m/<stdint.h>/){
```

Comment: `"#include <stdint.h>"."\n"` better written `"#include <stdint.h>\n"`

Comment: I cannot reproduce any error with this code. Although of course it does add the line every time, no matter if it is already there or not. Not multiple times, though.

Comment: got a way around. Although couldn't remove addition of line. But wrote a function to remove duplicate lines within header files only..thanks for your time

Comment: @Ad-vic: Your previous questions show that you can format your questions much better. Please improve this one so that we can help?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have this C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   return 0;
}
```

What is supposed to happen when this goes through your script?
*Nothing*, because  is already included

What actually happens though? This is where learning to use the Perl debugger or simply tracing by hand is really useful.

`flag` and `pos` are initialized to `0`. The first line in the file is `#include <stdio.h>` which *is not* `#include <stdint.h>`, so your code immediately assumes the file is missing and adds it.

So, in your above code you insert `#include <stdint.h>` on the first include that is not it, regardless of whether or not it is actually there later in the file or before, which will always be any other include file.

What you should actually do is gather all of the include lines in an Array, *then* search for the file matching `<stdint.h>` only adding it if it isn't contained in the complete list.

Comment: It also "works" if you put stdint.h first, in which case it simply skips that line and then adds it anyway.

Comment: so best thing to do is. check for duplication in header files and remove them. The code can be added just after addition of <stdint.h>

Comment: @Ad-vic That seems like extra work, you could just check for the file you want to include properly, then there would be no duplication.

Comment: thats why i am seeking help coz i dnt understand what i am doing wrong. Removing duplication will be my last resort

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
open(my $FILE, '<', $input) or die $!;
my @lines = <$FILE>;

my $flag = 0;
my $pos = 0;
my $insert_pos = 1; #add stdin even if there're no other include
foreach(@lines) {
    $pos++;
    if (/#include/){
        $insert_pos = $pos;
        if (/#include <stdint.h>/) {
            $insert_pos = 0;
            last;
        }
    }
}
if ($insert_pos) {
    splice @lines, $insert_pos, 0, "#include <stdint.h>"."\n";
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. No addition even if <stdint.h> not present

Comment: @Ad-vic: I didn't work if there're no other include. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is an awful thing to be doing to a C project.

What you have coded adds `#include <stdint.h>` right after the first `#include` line, and has no effect on files that don't `#include` anything.

However, if you want to "edit" a file using Perl, then you should use [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile)

The code in your question would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my ($input) = @ARGV;

tie my @c_file, 'Tie::File', $input or die qq{Unable to open C file "$input": $!};

for my $i (0 .. $#c_file) {
  next unless $c_file[$i] =~ /#include/;
  splice @c_file, $i, 0, '#include <stdint.h>';
  last;
}
```

Comment: how would some write a C file without any header file. Either system or user-defined header file must be there. In both cases #include will definitely come.

Comment: @Ad-vic: So, are you saying that my answer works for you? I want you to be aware that I have written something that duplicates your own code, and not something that I would recommend. It sounds like you should have a *project* header file where you can add `#include <stdint.h>` and anything else that comes along.

Comment: @Ad-vic: Please elaborate *"doesn't work"*. I tried to understand what you needed using both your question and your own algorithm, and write a solution using the `Tie::File` module. I guess I must have been close as I seem to have reproduced your bugs. Please explain properly what is wrong with the solutions you have so far, and what you really need?